# How to test class that calls other class

Tags: java, junit, junit4

If there is a method of a class like:

```
public String createA(String message) {
    . . .

    String sec = MDI.check(message, ..., ...);
    if sec == null throw . . . 

    return something;
}
```

What is the way to test `createA(message)` and mock, stub, ... the call to `MDI`. I mean, I want to check in the test that the call in `createA` to `MDI.check(...)` returns something I want.

```
@Test
public void testcreateA() {

}
```

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic

Comment: Ideally you would try to avoid the static call - can you make the method non static and inject an MDI instance into your class? A good read: [Google guide on Writing Testable Code](http://misko.hevery.com/attachments/Guide-Writing%20Testable%20Code.pdf).

Comment: Hi @assylias, non static yes, put inject no, createA is a REST GET operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you can use [PowerMock](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/) framework to mock the static call `MDI.check(message, ..., ...)` and then test your method.

Test class would be something like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MDI.class)
public class FooTest {

   @Test
   public void testCreateA() throws Exception {
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(MDI.class);
      PowerMockito.when(MDI.check(anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("Expected Answer");
      // test createA method
   }
}
```

Note you need to run the test with [PowerMockRunner](http://powermock.googlecode.com/svn/docs/powermock-1.5.1/apidocs/org/powermock/modules/junit4/PowerMockRunner.html).
There are a lot of examples in PowerMock [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) and some stackoverflow questions talking about it ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito))

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @troig, With PowerMock is possible to mock static objects, but I can not see in any examples how to mock the call inside the class tested :(

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm undertand you correctly... but I think my answer example is precisely doing this: `PowerMockito.when(MDI.check(anyString(), anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("Expected Answer");` I'm wrong?

Comment: Yes @troig, Sorry, I get it. Thanks!!!. Now I have problems between PowerMock and rest-assured http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401642/using-powermock-to-mock-static-class-in-a-rest-assured-test   :(